# Linearly independent set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and Gen{B} description

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, let $B = \{ a(3, 2, 0), b(1, -1, 0) \}$. I have to prove that B is linearly independent. So I have that, $\exists \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$
\alpha\left(3,2,0\right)+\beta\left(1,-1,0\right)=0 \\
\left(3\alpha+\beta,2\alpha-\beta,0\right)=0
$$

from which I get the equation system:

$$
3\alpha+\beta=0 \\
2\alpha-\beta=0
$$

By adding both equations:

$$
3\alpha+\beta+2\alpha-\beta=0 \\
5\alpha=0 \\
\alpha=0 \\
$$

And then:

$$
3\alpha+\beta=0 \\
3\left(0\right)+\beta=0 \\
\beta=0
$$

Therefore, B is linearly independent. Am I correct, so far?

Then I have to describe the space generated by B. So I don't get what the book means by "describing". As I understand it, the space generated by B is all the possible linear combinations of B, so the following combinations are in Gen{B}:

$$
1\left(a\right)+3\left(b\right)=\left(3+3\left(1\right),2+3\left(-1\right),0+3\left(0\right)\right)=\left(6,-1,0\right) \\
2\left(a\right)+1\left(b\right)=\left(2\left(3\right)+1\left(1\right),2\left(2\right)+2\left(-1\right),2\left(0\right)+2\left(0\right)\right)=\left(7,2,0\right) \\
\alpha\left(a\right)+\beta\left(b\right)=\left(3\alpha+\beta,2\alpha-\beta,0\alpha+0\beta\right)=\left(3\alpha+\beta,2\alpha-\beta,0\right)
$$

Would this be enough to "describe" Gen{B}? Do I need to add something else?

Comment: You are correct, but I think they are looking for the more succinct description "all vectors whose third component is zero."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant $B=\{ (3,2, 0), (1,-1,0)\}$.

To show that $B$ is linearly independent,  show that $$\alpha(3,2,0)+\beta(1,-1,0)=0 \implies \alpha = \beta = 0$$

To describe the space generated by $B$, it is a $2$-dimensional plane that passes through the origin. You can find the equation explicitly.

$$\begin{bmatrix}  3 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\times  \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ -5\end{bmatrix}$$

Hence the plane is $z=0$.

Comment: Yes, I though the book's notation looked funny... Anyway, I get what you say. I just can't find what describe means in this context, but I suppose what you proposed might do.